# Onion-peeling in O(n^2) time

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

I am working on the Onion-peeling problem, which is: given a number of points, return the amount of onion peels. For example, the one below has 5 onion peels.

[image]

At a high level pseudo-code, it is obvious that:

```
count = 0
while set has points:
    points = find points on convex hull
    set.remove(points) 
    count+=1
return count
```

But I'm asked to give this in O(n^2) time. Graham scan works in O(n*log(n)) time and gift-wrapping in O(n^2) time. Basically, I'm wondering which algorithm should I use internally to find the points on the convex hull efficiently?

If I use gift-wrapping: I'll get O(n^3) time, and with Graham, I'll get O(log(n)n^2) time.

What would be the best way to design an algorithm that solves the problem in O(n^2)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jarvis' March (Gift Wrapping) Algorithm takes $O(nh)$ time, where $h$ is number of points on convex hull.

**Hint:**

Suppose algorithm takes $i$ iterations to complete, and $h_k$ be the number of points on the $k$th convex hull $(1 \le k \le i )$. Also, let $n_k$ be the number of points remaining after first $k-1$ iterations. (Note that $n_1 = n, n_{i+1} = 0$).

What is $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^ih_k$?

**Explanation**:

Let the algorithm takes $cnh$ time for some $c > 0$.

At $k$th iteration, the algorithm will take $cn_kh_k$ time.

The algorithm terminates after $i$ iterations. Therefore, the total time taken for the algorithm is:
$$\begin{align}\mathrm{Time} &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^i c n_k h_k
\\&= c\sum\limits_{k = 1}^i n_k h_k
\\&\le c\sum\limits_{k = 1}^i n h_k\qquad \text{because }\quad n_k \le n 
\\&= cn \sum\limits_{k = 1}^i h_k
\\&= cn \cdot n \qquad \text{because } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^i h_k \text{is total number of points removed in all iterations, which is n}
\\&= cn^2
\\&= O(n^2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: But if n=h, then it will take `O(n^2)`... right?

Comment: Then, there will be only one iteration and you're done, right?

Comment: Err, the summation should be: `i*(n-lost_points)*h`;

Comment: No, there is no dependency on $i$. Let the time for GW algorithm be $cnh$ for some $c$. So, total time will be $cnh_1 + cn_1h_2 + \cdots + cn_ih_i \le cn \sum_{k = 1}^i h_i$, because each $n_i \le n$. After the last step, you should use the hint in the answer. $n_k$ is number of points left after first $k-1$ iterations.

Comment: Thanks. So I should be able to expand the summation with, http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/c/1/8c13104b74e13a61a0beb44fa8d6e46b.png ? That would give me `O(cn*(i(i+1))/2)`

Comment: Actually, $h_k$ is the points which you remove in $k$th iteration. After all $i$ iterations, you remove $\sum h_k$ points in all, and you're left with $0$ points. What does that imply about relation between number of points you began with ( $= n$) and $\sum h_k$?

Comment: Err - I really am not sure. I think that `h[k]` decreases by `h[k-1]` for each subsequent onion peel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17487/discussion-between-taninamdar-and-user1008537).